# Natural Join in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, oracle10g

How can I achieve `NATURAL JOIN` i.e. joining two tables based on all the matching columns  in Hibernate 3.2.5?

On the broader way, I can put restrictions wherever I want to achieve the `Natural Join`. I want to perform the `NATURAL JOIN` on all the matching columns of the two tables without writing restrictions again and again.

**Note:**

This is just a code refactoring  with a view of decreasing the LOC.

Is this feasible in a easier way?

Please let me know about this.

Comment: I consider using a natural join bad coding style. It's too easy to break stuff if you change the table definitions.

Comment: Consider reformatting the post to separate code from text.